# What's the official name for pop up window that opens up near tags [picture included]

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a documentation and I am not sure whats the proper term for this small window.

[Window expands to to configure properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0W9e.png)

[image]

forgive my ignorance but what is the feature called?

Comment: I'd call it a context menu.

Comment: Id call it a 'Task Window' as it always contains the name 'tasks'

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+smart+tag&oq=visual+studio+smart&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.5303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a smart tag​​​​.